# Combine scripts from all extensions of the plugin when an extension is activated

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing a WordPress plugin whose functionality can be extended by other plugins. The extensions simple WordPress plugins but just adds functionality by adding hooks.

- My main plugin loads the JavaScript files for the base functionality.
- All extensions have their own JavaScript files
- My main JavaScript file need to invoke certain JavaScript methods of the extensions
- So all extensions are extending the class in the main JavaScript file
- All my extensions add a filter to return their script location to the main plugin.
- The main plugin then loads them in `enqueue_admin_scripts` hook in a specific order

Since there can be too many such script files loaded on the page, I want to concatenate all of them, and possibly minify, into a single file.

I tried to hook the `register_activation_hook` to get and combine all scripts, however, as per docs, this hook should not be used in `plugins_loaded` hook or any other hook. My extensions filter is not getting executed from this hook to get their scripts locations. So I cannot get the locations of all activated plugins.

Is there any other hook that I can use to do this concatenation one time when any extension is activated/deactivated?

Comment: Let's suppose that you find the hook that will allow you to perform an action whenever a new extension of your plugin is activated/deactivated. How do you plan to concatenate and minify the scripts? You'd store the resulting JS file somewhere I assume.

Comment: The resulting file should be stored in a subdirectory under the main plugin directory